# How to do this XML declaration in Flex4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, flex4, mxml

I have a dataProvider that's defined with `mx:XML` like this.

```
<mx:dataProvider>
   <mx:XML format="e4x">
      <root label="All Items">   
         <morning label="Evening" type="check" />
         <evening label="Evening" type="check" />
         <night label="Night" type="check" />
      </root>
   </mx:XML>
</mx:dataProvider>
```

This doesn't seem to be a valid option anymore with the new spark architecture. Can someone suggest how this can be done? I thought if I put in Declarations, it would work, but doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<fx:XML>
...
</fx:XML>
```

Comment: Very strange. Now it worked, even though it didn't appear in code hinting before when I tried it. Looks like something weird with code hinting because I can't get `<fx:Declarations>` either